# Spring Boot ConstraintValidator problem with null @PathVariable

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, validation, spring-mvc

I created a custom validator in Spring Boot but when I pass the `@PathVariable` value to the validator, it gets the parameter name for null values.

```
@Validated // added for controller

@GetMapping("/employees/{code}")
    public ResponseEntity<ApiResponse<List<RunwayBean>>> findByCode(
            @ValidInput @PathVariable("code") String code) {

        // ...
    }
```

```
@Documented
@Target({FIELD, METHOD, PARAMETER, ANNOTATION_TYPE, TYPE_USE})
@Retention(RUNTIME)
@Constraint(validatedBy = {InputValidator.class})
public @interface ValidInput {

    String message() default INVALID_INPUT;

    Class<?>[] groups() default {};

    Class<? extends Payload>[] payload() default {};
}
```

And then in the validator below, `str` value is `:code` when I pass the parameter null on Postman. But when I add any string, it can be received correctly. So, how can I fix it?

```
public class InputValidator implements ConstraintValidator<ValidInput, String> {

    @Override
    public void initialize(ValidInput constraintAnnotation) {}

    @Override
    public boolean isValid(String str, ConstraintValidatorContext context) {
        return str!= null && !str.isBlank();
        // str = ":code" when @PathVariable value is null
    }
}
```

Comment: are you sure you send the right request with postman? `:code` shouldn't appear out of nowhere

Comment: @zapl Are you there?

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to accomplish. If you're sending a request to `http://localhost:8080/api/v1/runways/code/:code`, how on Earth is it surprising that `code == ":code"`?

Comment: @crisis RE-read the question, you seem to not understood

Comment: I have, and I still don't understand what it's supposed to mean to pass `null` as a path variable. If you send a request with the URL `http://localhost:8080/api/v1/runways/code/`, it will not match your controller method. If, on the other hand, you send `http://localhost:8080/api/v1/runways/code/null`, the parameter will have the value of the literal string `"null"`. What's the syntax you were hoping to use for the URL that would result in the parameter actually 'being' `null`? There is no such syntax to the best of my knowledge.

Comment: I wrote the tried url wrong, sorry. It must be `http://localhost:8080/api/v1/employees/:code`. Any idea?

Comment: On the other hand, when I use `@RequestParam()` instead of `@PathVariable` it is working like a charm. But I would prefer using  `@PathVariable` . Any idea?

Comment: Idea about what? I asked you a question, let me reiterate: What's the syntax you were hoping to use for the URL that would result in the parameter actually 'being' null?

Comment: @Crsisis Chico, I use correct syntax and f not, the request would not pass to the validator.

Comment: @gonzales Can you please add request where you are passing path variable as null ?

Comment: On Postman, I send `http://localhost:8080/api/v1/employees/:code` with null code parameter. But if you set its value (code) as whitespace, it is working.

Comment: @Vikrant_chail Chico? Are you there?

Comment: @gonzales You are passing :code as you parameter not null

Comment: @Vikrant_chail What do you mean?

Comment: If you define a request like `http://localhost/foo/:code` and you don't put anything into the path variable field in postman it will in some cases send the request as a literal request to `http://localhost/foo/:code` and now `:code` is literally the value of your path variable in spring. If you don't want to send anything for that path segment, make a request to `http://localhost/foo/` Path segments don't work too well for optional parameters

Comment: Thanks for reply. Then I think I should use @RequestParam, right?